# Thesis using MIT template using \typein to address other files

Tags: typein

I'm typesetting a thesis using the MIT thesis template. There was a prior question asked before here: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/97109/revisions

```
    \typein [\files]{all}
    \def\all{}
    \ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi
```

I'm still in the beginning stages of understanding LaTeX. I would like to "type in" all files to process in the above code for which I used `{all}` in brackets as was prescribed in the answer to the previous question asked on this matter. However, I receive the following error message:

```
    Emergency stop. \typein[\files]{all}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The link you provided is dead. I think, Typing `all` is a misunderstanding here. With `all` you would include only a file named `all.tex` here! The `{all}` as argument to `\typein` is just the prompt! If your files are called `chap1.tex`, `chap2.tex`, you could use `chap1,chap2` as input to `\typein`

Comment: Turns out you can just comment out those 3 lines and it'll compile all your files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must test if `\files` and `\all` would expand to the same content.

Entering `all` at the input prompt, `\files` will contain just this token `all`. Now, to compare for the same content, `\all` must expand to have the same value, i.e. `\def\all{all}`.

If the test fails, it should include only those in the list, i.e. `chap1` for example.

The problem with a `\typein` is that it has to be used twice to make the links and ToC information correct, as usual, i.e. twice inputs are necessary.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents}{chap1}
\chapter{One}


\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chap2}
\chapter{Two}


\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chap3}
\chapter{Three}


\end{filecontents}



\typein [\files]{all}

\def\all{all}
\ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome and for helping me understand this better! Is the beginning of this sample code after `\documentclass{book}` up until `\typein [\files]{all}` what you mean by testing to see if the expansion is the same for `\files` and `\all`?  Sorry I'm having trouble parsing even the basic elements here but am still eager to understand. I'm also not finding a lot by way of documentation on this note.

Comment: @DeborahWeissner: The test itself is `\ifx\files\all ...`, which must be terminated by a `\fi`.

Comment: Ah, please pardon my ignorance! After hours upon hours of toiling, googling, rereading this, altering and unaltering, I have a better grasp of this now. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my abilities so far this is how I understand this now:

1. `\typein [\files]` asks for input of file names or all for all file
       names from the TeX user upon running the script. It prompts the user
       with:

   ```
   “Enter file names to process, (chapter1, chap2…), or `all’ to
   process all files:”

   This assigns the file names given or the word “all” to a macro
   called `\files`
   ```
2. `\def\all{all}`

   Creates a macro called `\all` representing "all"
3. `\ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else
   \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi`

   A special if conditional statement that can compare macro
   definitions using `\ifx` If the user's response was (a)"all", then
   this was assigned to `\files` and the equality in the conditional
   statement holds and the test is true so all files are included as by
   default, but if (b) only certain files were specified, then the
   equality of "all" (represented by the `\all` macro definition) does
   not hold, the test is not true and thus the second argument in the
   conditional which both types out and redisplays the names of the
   files specified by the user in the prompt, assigned to `\files`, and
   the following output is restricted to those files as specified in
   the second part of the second argument in the conditional:
   `\includeonly{\files}`

Comment: Well, I thought you know about the commands,otherwise I would have explained this even further in my answer (+1)